# Hide the plot and display only the legend og certain plot when using ggarange()

Tags: r, ggplot2

Below I create 3 plots. In the first 2 I want only the plots and not the legend, while in the 3rd I want to display only the legend. I want to combine those 3 in one with `ggarange()`. But instead of having only the legend I get nothing in the 3rd one. How could I do it?

[image]

```
library(ggplot2) 
library(grid)
library(gridExtra) 

my_hist1 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = cut)) + 
  geom_bar() +theme(legend.position = "none")
my_hist2 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = cut)) + 
  geom_bar() +theme(legend.position = "none")
my_hist3 <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = cut)) + 
  geom_bar() 

# Using the cowplot package
legend <- cowplot::get_legend(my_hist3)

grid.newpage()
grid.draw(legend)

ggarrange(my_hist1,my_hist2,grid.draw(legend) + rremove("x.text"), 
          labels = c("1", "2", "Score.Type"),
          ncol = 3, nrow = 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[patchwork](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/) can aggregate legends for you:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

my_hist <- ggplot(diamonds, aes(clarity, fill = cut)) + geom_bar()

my_hist + my_hist + plot_layout(guides = 'collect')
```

[image: two plots with aggregated legend]

Comment: what if I want to combine it with ggarange in order to achieve certain ways that the plots will be displayed?

Comment: What ways? patchwork can do a lot in its idiom, and since it's still working within the grid framework, it can sometimes interoperate with other similar packages like gridExtra and cowplot. As much as possible, try to keep it simple for your own sanity, though; there's no reason to learn the intricacies of grid to combine and annotate a couple plots.